# How can I combine two code at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Question: The information of the youngest and oldest employee at the same time.

I can find information of the youngest or oldest employee, but I can't find information of the youngest and oldest employee at the same time.

My sql query:

```
-- The information of the oldest employee
    Select top 1*
    From DIP_Employees1
    where DogumTarihi=
        (Select Min(DogumTarihi)
         From DIP_Employees1
        )

-- The information of the youngest employee
    Select top 1*
    From DIP_Employees1
    where DogumTarihi=
        (Select Max(DogumTarihi)
         From DIP_Employees1
        )
```

How can I combine this two code for at the same time?

Comment: may be with an `union statement`

Comment: With a `UNION`?

Comment: For starters I would use an ORDER BY instead of subquery for this. Then you can simply stick a UNION ALL between the two queries and get both.

Comment: By the way, datatype of DogumTarihi is datetime.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine 2 queries that return same columns using [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement.

Also it is unnecessary to use subqueries. Instead you can just use order by

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    Select top 1 *
    From DIP_Employees1
    ORDER BY DogumTarihi ASC
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
    Select top 1 *
    From DIP_Employees1
    ORDER BY DogumTarihi DESC
) t2
```

Comment: @Bobayobasiren With the correct index this solution will blow all the others out of the water

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
with cte as (
   select min(DogumTarihi) as mndg, max(DogumTarihi) as mxdg 
     from dbo.DIP_Employees1 
)
select ... 
  from dbo.DIP_Employees1 as emp 
 inner join cte on emp.DogumTarihi = cte.mndg
        or emp.DogumTarihi = cte.maxdg
order by ...
;
```

Notice that some suggestions assume birthdate is unique. However unlikely it might be that multiple persons will have the same birthdate, why assume at all?

Comment: I will add that I have been in an organization where twins were both employees.